# Refreshing page gives Cannot GET /page_url in react-router 2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using client side rendering with react 0.14 and react-router 2. I have deployed my app to a local node server.

I am at `url (server_url/component1)`. Whenenver I refresh the page I am getting

```
Cannot GET /component1
```

error from server side.

I know this is happening because I am sending request to server again for `/component1` which route does not exists on server. But I want to disable that whenever I am refreshing the page it should handled by client side routing only. I do not want to send any request to server.

Entry point to my app index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Router,browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router routes={routes} history={browserHistory}/>
  , document.querySelector('.init')
);
```

My routes.js file

```
module.exports = (
       <Route path="/" component={App}>
           <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
           <Route path="/component1" component={comp1}/>
       </Route>
)
```

**Edit:**
In this scenario should I use browser history or hash history? Are they same?

Comment: Do you use any framework on server side?

Comment: I am using express server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, then you have to redirect all your requests, that don't match defined routes, to the *frontend*. If it is just a static html file, the route should look like:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('public/index.html');
});
```

**UPDATE**

To let other routes work, you should put them just in front of *catching* route, since express applies them vice versa (the first defined route will be applied as the last one):

```
app.get('/any_route_here', (req, res) => {
  res.json({msg: 'ROUTE WORKS'})
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('public/index.html'); //pas routing to react
});
```

In such a way, if you hit a request like: `yourserver.host/any_route_here` you will get a json message **ROUTE WORKS**, but on any other request, the routing will be passed to your frontend.

Comment: I am using some other routes as well e.g `/auth` but if I use wild route capture then It wont allow to go to other routes.