# Can I create routes with react-router for a github-pages site?

Tags: javascript, react-router, url-routing, single-page-application, github-pages

Ok, so I've made a SPA using React and React-Router and have pushed it to github pages, but none of the routes I have written work when I refresh or click back in my browser. I had the same problem when I was serving the page locally, but then followed along to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36141859/refreshing-page-gives-cannot-get-page-url-in-react-router-2) and made a server.js file which provided a redirect to my static HTML page at each route. Here is what the file looks like:

```
"use strict";
let express = require('express');
let path = require('path');


let app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/contact', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile('public/index.html', { root: __dirname });
})

app.get('/about', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile('public/index.html', { root: __dirname });
})

app.get('*', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile('public/index.html', { root: __dirname });
})

app.listen(8080, function(){
  console.log('Listening on port 8080!')
})
```

Now, my problem is that when I push the project to github pages all of that logic is ignored, github's routing takes over and I have the same problem of not being able to refresh or go straight to `/contact` or `/about`. I know it seems like an obvious problem to run into, since github pages is designed to only host static sites, but I've seen people hinting towards other ways of creating a static page for each route, such as the answer in [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/39tlb0/has_anyone_done_reactrouter_using_historylocation/cs6cbrn/), but I have no idea how to do that.

I should also mention that because I already have a site at `user-name.github.io`, so this site is being hosted at `user-name.github.io/projects`, making that my `/` route. I have no idea if this makes any difference, I just thought I should mention it.

I think I've pretty much exhausted every option to try and successfully host this on gh-pages and I know there are projects like [Single Page Apps for GitHub Pages](https://github.com/rafrex/spa-github-pages) to try and fix this issue but, I just wanted to see if anyone out there has had any luck doing this before resorting to that.

FYI, here is my **app.js** (containing routing logic):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute} from 'react-router';
//Import custom components
import About from '../components/about.js';
import Contact from '../components/contact.js';
import Sidebar from '../components/sidebar.js';
import Imagelist from '../components/image-list.js';


  render(
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Sidebar}>
          <IndexRoute component={Imagelist}/>
          <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
          <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
        </Route>
      </Router>,
      document.getElementById('content')
    );
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated & happy to include more code if helpful.

Comment: express is a backend framework to write api routes... what do you trying to achieve with gh static pages? you want to gh page points to a api in another domain?

Comment: I used express because that was what was suggested in another SO answer, but yes, I know I can't include any of this logic when I push it to gh-pages. Just trying to see if there is any advice on creating a static page for each route.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you need to change your browserHistory to a hashHistory.. so you can use it with gh... it changes path from /home to #/home

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. I read that hashHistory isn't recommended for production but, for now, it's a good compromise since browserHistory requires me to configure a server, which isn't possible when hosting on gh-pages.

Answer (score 5):

Aside from using `hashHistory` as suggested in the accepted answer, there is another workaround. Look [here](https://github.com/rafrex/spa-github-pages).

Basically, you create a spoof `404.html` file which has a script that converts the requested path into the query string & redirects the browser to the index page with the query string attached to the URL. After the index file is loaded, the original path is restored from the query string & `ReactRouter` picks up the changes.

A neat solution, but not production-ready, either.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using create-react-app (I haven't tested this in any other environment) you can use `browserRouter`, you will need to pass a `basename` prop to the component with this env variable: `process.env.PUBLIC_URL`.

Your router should now look like this:

```
<BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
  {/* routes */}
</BrowserRouter>
```

For more info you can checkout this [Github thread](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1765)

> Use process.env.PUBLIC_URL in your route definitions so that they work both in development and after deployment. For example: . This will be empty in development and ... (inferred from homepage) in production.

Comment: Anyone know if this works without create-react-app? I'm using parcel

Answer (score 3):

To extend Jildert's answer, I did the same - copied index.html to 404.html before deploying to the github pages and it worked.

So I've just updated pre-deploy section of package.json to include this copy action and now it works fine with BrowserRouter:

```
"predeploy": "npm run build && cp build/index.html build/404.html",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
```

Answer (score 2):

I just found a solution for this without using the HashRouter. I created a little node script that's called before my deployment script that creates a 404.html file with the same content as the index.html. Github pages serves that file if you refresh on a page in your react-app.

```
const fs = require('fs')
fs.copyFile('build/index.html', 'build/404.html', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log('index.html was copied to 404.html')
})
```