# How to Deploy CRA to GitHub Pages Using React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, github-pages, create-react-app, react-dom

I have been majorly trapped by this curve ball.

I have a site built w/ **create react app** which I'd like to deploy to GitHub Pages, however, I've hit a blocker with **React Router.**

I understand GitHub pages work flawlessly w/ static content, but:

**1- what is the correct solution to deploy to GitHub pages with SPA using react router ?**

I tried all sort of configuration and none worked.

my routes are configured as:

**Index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import App from './App';
render(<Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}><App /></Router>, 
 document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Routes.js**

```
import { Route, Switch, Redirect, HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
...

const Routes = () => (
    <Switch>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
        <Route path='/contact' exact component={Contact} />
        <Route path='/about/faculty' exact component={Faculty} />
        <Route path='/about/what-we-do' exact component={Mission} />
        <Redirect from='/about/' to='/about/faculty' />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
)
export default Routes;
```

I tried wrapping my `<Switch/>` with `<HashRouter/>` but that made the routes no longer work.

**My Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-site",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://username.github.io/project_name",
  "dependencies": {
    ...

    "react-router": "4.2.0",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "0.24.4",
    "react-router-dom": "4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

After issuing a `yarn build` and `yarn run deploy` the site gets published to this page which holds no content at all, and naturally any route I try hitting gives me a **404.**

[image]

**2- Regarding the package.json what is the correct config for the homepage?:**

`"homepage": "https://username.github.io/project_name"`
or 
`"homepage": "https://username.github.io"`

As an end result, I'd like the site to be served under the `https://username.github.io` URL, so I'm confused about what is the correct configuration.

3 - I read docs stating that I should deploy under the `gh pages branch` which is actually not showing on my GitHub. I only get the option to publish to master.

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/rafrex/spa-github-pages

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I create routes with react-router for a github-pages site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40776651/can-i-create-routes-with-react-router-for-a-github-pages-site)