# Deployed CRA app on github pages (with custom domain) using travis CI but only showing readme.md

Tags: reactjs, deployment, travis-ci, github-pages

I am using Travis CI to deploy my create-react-app on github project page (https://jaanhio.github.io/ollidia-front-end) and i am facing 2 issues.

1. Routing issue where it returns empty page on load as react-router is not configured for that route. in my case, no such route `<Route to="ollidia-front-end" component={component} />`. i believe it can be solved via answers from this [Can I create routes with react-router for a github-pages site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40776651/can-i-create-routes-with-react-router-for-a-github-pages-site). Have yet to try it but any advice will be appreciated
2. i tried using custom domain (http://ollida.club) with this github project page. However, the only thing that loads is readme.md. I am not sure how can i configure the travis.yml or package.json to solve this.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ollidia_front",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "gh-pages": "^1.1.0",
    "material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.43",
    "material-ui-icons": "^1.0.0-beta.36",
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^4.2.9",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "react-stripe-checkout": "^2.6.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.3.2",
    "react-youtube": "^7.6.0",
    "styled-components": "^3.2.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "CI=false yarn run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "homepage": "http://ollida.club/"
}
```

travis.yml

```
language: node_js
warnings_are_errors: false
node_js:
  - "node"
install:
  - yarn install --ignore-engines
after_success:
  - git config --global user.name "jaanhio"
  - git config --global user.email "xxx@gmail.com"
  - git remote rm origin
  - git remote add origin https://jaanhio:${GH_TOKEN}@github.com/jaanhio/ollidia-front-end.git
  - yarn run deploy
```