# React-Router: Gitlab-pages show 404 error on refreshing

Tags: reactjs, react-router, gitlab, gitlab-pages

Im new to react and gitlab pages hosting and im currently hosting my first app on gitlab-pages. Few days ago i added react-router-dom to navigate between specific pages/routes. The routing works fine, but when i try to refresh any page on gitlab expect the "/" home domain, i get a 404 error (e.g. im on the /booked route and press F5 my gitlab gives me the 404 error). Is there anything wrong with my configuration? See it below:

```
...
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
const routing = (
 <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />

    <Route path="/booking" render={props => <Child {...props} />} />
    <Route
     path="/booked" render={props => <ChildChild{...props} />}
    />
    <Route path="/bookedd" component={ChildChildChild} />
   </div>
  </Router>
   );

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById("root"));
```

and here is my gitlab-ci.yml:

```
test:
  image: node:9.6.1
  stage: test
  script:
     - npm install;  npm run test
  pages:
  image: node:9.6.1
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    PUBLIC_URL: "/pageName"
  script:
    - rm package.json; mv package.json.pages package.json; 
      npm install;npm install react-scripts@1.1.1 -g;npm run build
    - rm -rf public; mv build public
  artifacts:
  paths:
    - public 
  only:
    - master
```

If there is no real solution for the 404 error, is it possible to redirect any refresh attempt to the "/" home route?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I create routes with react-router for a github-pages site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40776651/can-i-create-routes-with-react-router-for-a-github-pages-site)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use `HashRouter` instead of `BrowserRouter` ... It will put `#` in the URL after your project name